# Prevent commit in procedure when called sub procedure fails

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two procedures, both of which do variours inserts.  Procedure B is called by Procedure A.

If any of the inserts in procA fail then all is well and no commits are made.  However if something in procB fails my inserts in procA are still committing.  How do I prevent this happening.  I just need to ensure that if anything in the procedure OR sub-procedure fails then none of the inserts are committed.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procA;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE procA(parama INT, 
                       paramb VARCHAR(50))
  BEGIN

     INSERT INTO .......
     INSERT INTO .......
     call procB(@paramx, parama);


  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procB;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE procB(paramx INT, 
                       parama INT)
  BEGIN

     INSERT INTO .......

  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make procedure a function - then rollback on an error code